# I am trying to make a powershell script to bulk import users to an enterprise application but keep receiving errors

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Here is the code that I have written and modified several times, but still cannot get to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I keep receiving the following errors:

**`Get-AzureADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null** and **New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.`**

```
# Assign the global values to the variables for the script.

$app_name = "App Name"

$app_role_name = "User"

$users = Get-Content 'Path\Users.txt'

$Credential=Get-StoredCredential -UserName #####

# Connect to Azure AD using Azure AD Powershell
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential

# Get the user to assign, and the service principal for the app to assign to
foreach ($user in $users) {

$AADuser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user

$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"

$appRole = $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $app_role_name }

# Assign the user to the app role
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id

}'''
```

Comment: Looks like you might have empty lines in `Path\Users.txt`. Try `$users = Get-Content 'Path\Users.txt' |Where-Object {$_}`

Comment: No empty lines in the text file, but I receive the same error when trying a csv.

Comment: Please show the `Users.txt` file and the csv file here, otherwise we could not help you.